# Angular select multiple with bootstrap-select.js and ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I´m having problems with a select multiple in angular. I´m using the library bootstrap-select.js and I have to assign the values in ng-options, but when I write the multiple attribute it brokes the select.

```
<select 
    ng-show="vm.showAuidit" 
    id="select_audits"
    class="form-control selectpicker"
    tabindex="-1"
    ng-model='vm.type'  
    ng-change="vm.selectType()"
    ng-init="vm.selectType()"
    ng-selected="type.value === vm.type"
    ng-options='type.value as type.name for type in vm.types'
    ng-disabled="vm.selectEnable()"
    multiple title="">
</select>
```

Does anybody knows how to implement a good select multipleworking with ng-options?

thanks!

Comment: `ng-options` use `vm.types` whereas ng-model has `vm.type`. This might be causing problem

Comment: vm.type is for ng-selected only in this case. If i put the code without multiple keyword it works and if I put the code without ng-options and qith <option></option> it works, but I need to use ng-options in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this changing the multi select library for angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.min.js

```
<select
    ng-show="vm.showAuidit"
    id="select_localizaciones"
    class="form-control" 
    tabindex="-1"
    ng-model='vm.localizaciones'  
    ng-change="vm.selectType()"
    ng-init="vm.selectType()"
    ng-options='localizacion.value as localizacion.name for localizacion in vm.localizaciones'
    ng-disabled="vm.selectEnable()"
    required>
</select>
```

for doc: [angularjs-dropdown-multiselect](http://myforce.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/)